# How to determine if a gtk grid is being clipped?

Tags: grid, gtk, clip

I have a GTK grid (allocated and initialized) in a top-level root window (homogeneous rows and columns) which covers the entire physical display.  I'd like to display all of the various contained widgets, but sometimes the rightmost grid entries are getting clipped. In such a case I would like to detect that the display has clipped the grid and automatically to retry with a smaller font. How may I accomplish this? (I'm using gtk v3)

I've mostly tried searches to find an answer, both via duckduckgo and via SO's search. Lots of hits on visible (not useful, the grid and its contained widgets are all visible), clipping areas, etc.

Comment: Please add a minimal and reproducible example so we can "see" the actual issue.

Comment: Well, that's a problem that would take me days to produce. What I have estimates a grid cell size (a generic widget to be attached)  and chooses a font based on that. It builds an example and instantiates it in a popup window, using gtk_widget_size_request() to find out how big the resulting window is, and embeds it in a loop to find an appropriate fontsize. Is there nothing to determine whether a cell (ie. the widget in the cell) has been clipped? I have ready access to the widget at the upper right corner that is attached to the grid. The grid widgets are typically labels.

Comment: I hope you get an answer, but this is not how SO typically works.